# Background not working on Pygame project

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.init


def color1():

    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    backgound.fill((0,0,255))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))


    pygame.display.flip()


color1()
pygame.quit()
```

I've been trying to make a game, and everything used to work, but as of yesterday night, nothing will show up. I decided to make a small game and build back up to where I was, but whenever I run the code above, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\thing.py", line 16, in <module>
    color1()
  File "C:\Python32\thing.py", line 9, in color1
    backgound.fill((0,0,255))
NameError: global name 'backgound' is not defined
```

Any help at all would be appreciated, this is really annoying and I feel like I'm simply overlooking something.

Comment: I think you need to call the pygame.init function, not just check its existence.

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you misspelled your variable name `background`. (you forgot the `r`).
Also you don't need to build a surface for this, you can just fill the screen.

Also as Darthfett pointed out, you acually need to call `pygame.init()`

Comment: Thank you, my eyes are a little strained, so I didn't catch that mistake!